# Delphi constants and references

Tags: delphi, constants, pass-by-reference, delphi-2007

I want to pass constant references to functions in delphi, so I am sure that the referenced object won't change and to save time and memory. So I want to declare a function like

```
function foo(var const Value : Bar) : Boolean;
```

however this is not allowed. I thought constant values would be automatically sent as references. However I found out that it is not the case (getting the address of an object before sending it to the function gives me $12F50C and the address of the same object inside the function is $12F564)

What can I do to send constant references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function Foo(Const Value:Bar):Boolean` passes the value in the "most efficient" way, for large objects this is usualy by reference but smaller objects tend to get passed by value.

[The answers to this question go into more detail...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951192/delphi-performance-of-passing-const-strings-versus-passing-var-strings)

Note that passing a parameter marked as `const` doesn't mean it can't be changed, it just means the compiler won't let you directly change it.