# Is the use of `const` dogmatic or rational?

Tags: delphi, parameters, constants

In Delphi you can speed up your code by passing parameters as `const`, e.g.

```
function A(const AStr: string): integer;

//or

function B(AStr: string): integer;
```

Suppose both functions have the same code inside, the speed difference between them is negligible and I doubt it can even be measured with a cycle-counter like:

```
function RDTSC: comp;
var
  TimeStamp: record case byte of
    1: (Whole: comp);
    2: (Lo, Hi: Longint);
  end;
begin
  asm
    db $0F; db $31;
    mov [TimeStamp.Lo], eax
    mov [TimeStamp.Hi], edx
  end;
  Result := TimeStamp.Whole;
end;
```

The reason for this is that all the `const` does in function A is to prevent the reference count of `AStr` to be incremented.
But the increment only takes one cycle of one core of my multicore CPU, so...

Why should I bother with `const`?

Comment: @RRUZ: I don't think it is a duplicate. This is `const` vs. nothing, not `const` vs. `var`.

Comment: @all, thank you for enlightening me on the try finally issue. I do have one more issue about const. But maybe I should bring that up in a separate question. (is const thread safe?)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If there is no other reason for the function to contain an implicit try/finally, and the function itself is not doing much work, the use of const can result in a significant speedup (I once got one function that was using >10% of total runtime in a profiling run down to <2% just by adding a const in the right place).

Also, the reference counting takes much much more than one cycle because it has to be performed with the lock prefix for threadsafety reasons, so we are talking more like 50-100 cycles. More if something in the same cache line has been modified by another core in between.

As for not being able to measure it:

```
program Project;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Math;

function GetThreadTime: Int64;
var
  CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime: TFileTime;
begin
  GetThreadTimes(GetCurrentThread, CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime);
  Result := PInt64(@UserTime)^;
end;

function ConstLength(const s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(s);
end;

function NoConstLength(s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(s);
end;

var
  s : string;
  i : Integer;
  j : Integer;

  ConstTime, NoConstTime: Int64;

begin
  try
    // make sure we got an heap allocated string;
    s := 'abc';
    s := s + '123';

    //make sure we minimize thread context switches during the timing
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    j := 0;
    ConstTime := GetThreadTime;
    for i := 0 to 100000000 do
      Inc(j, ConstLength(s));
    ConstTime := GetThreadTime - ConstTime;

    j := 0;
    NoConstTime := GetThreadTime;
    for i := 0 to 100000000 do
      Inc(j, NoConstLength(s));
    NoConstTime := GetThreadTime - NoConstTime;

    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    WriteLn('Const: ', ConstTime);
    WriteLn('NoConst: ', NoConstTime);
    WriteLn('Const is ',  (NoConstTime/ConstTime):2:2, ' times faster.');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  if DebugHook <> 0 then
    ReadLn;
end.
```

Produces this output on my system:

```
Const: 6084039
NoConst: 36192232
Const is 5.95 times faster.
```

EDIT: it gets a bit more interesting if we add some thread contention:

```
program Project;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Math;

function GetThreadTime: Int64;
var
  CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime: TFileTime;
begin
  GetThreadTimes(GetCurrentThread, CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime);
  Result := PInt64(@UserTime)^;
end;

function ConstLength(const s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(s);
end;

function NoConstLength(s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(s);
end;

function LockedAdd(var Target: Integer; Value: Integer): Integer; register;
asm
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     eax, edx
   lock xadd    [ecx], eax
        add     eax, edx
end;

var
  x : Integer;
  s : string;

  ConstTime, NoConstTime: Integer;

  StartEvent: THandle;

  ActiveCount: Integer;
begin
  try
    // make sure we got an heap allocated string;
    s := 'abc';
    s := s + '123';

    ConstTime := 0;
    NoConstTime := 0;

    StartEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, '');

    ActiveCount := 0;
    for x := 0 to 2 do
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
      var
        i : Integer;
        j : Integer;
        ThreadConstTime: Int64;
      begin
        //make sure we minimize thread context switches during the timing
        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);

        InterlockedIncrement(ActiveCount);
        WaitForSingleObject(StartEvent, INFINITE);
        j := 0;
        ThreadConstTime := GetThreadTime;
        for i := 0 to 100000000 do
          Inc(j, ConstLength(s));
        ThreadConstTime := GetThreadTime - ThreadConstTime;

        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

        LockedAdd(ConstTime, ThreadConstTime);
        InterlockedDecrement(ActiveCount);
      end).Start;

    while ActiveCount < 3 do
      Sleep(100);

    SetEvent(StartEvent);

    while ActiveCount > 0 do
      Sleep(100);

    WriteLn('Const: ', ConstTime);

    ResetEvent(StartEvent);

    for x := 0 to 2 do
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
      var
        i : Integer;
        j : Integer;
        ThreadNoConstTime: Int64;
      begin
        //make sure we minimize thread context switches during the timing
        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);

        InterlockedIncrement(ActiveCount);
        WaitForSingleObject(StartEvent, INFINITE);
        j := 0;
        ThreadNoConstTime := GetThreadTime;
        for i := 0 to 100000000 do
          Inc(j, NoConstLength(s));
        ThreadNoConstTime := GetThreadTime - ThreadNoConstTime;

        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

        LockedAdd(NoConstTime, ThreadNoConstTime);
        InterlockedDecrement(ActiveCount);
      end).Start;

    while ActiveCount < 3 do
      Sleep(100);

    SetEvent(StartEvent);

    while ActiveCount > 0 do
      Sleep(100);

    WriteLn('NoConst: ', NoConstTime);
    WriteLn('Const is ',  (NoConstTime/ConstTime):2:2, ' times faster.');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  if DebugHook <> 0 then
    ReadLn;
end.
```

On a 6 core machine, this gives me:

```
Const: 19968128
NoConst: 1313528420
Const is 65.78 times faster.
```

EDIT2: replacing the call to Length with a call to Pos (I picked the worst case, search for something not contained in the string):

```
function ConstLength(const s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Pos('x', s);
end;

function NoConstLength(s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := Pos('x', s);
end;
```

results in:

```
Const: 51792332
NoConst: 1377644831
Const is 26.60 times faster.
```

for the threaded case, and:

```
Const: 15912102
NoConst: 44616286
Const is 2.80 times faster.
```

for the non-threaded case.

Comment: thankfully the try finally penalty will largely vanish in x86-64.

Comment: of course this benchmark is very artificial because the function does nothing

Comment: I strongly disagree that the benchmark is "very artificial". Because the function does something. It returns the length of the string. That's hardly nothing is it? But I've added benchmark results for a more complex case which still shows significant speed difference. On the topic of try/finally overhead. The overhead for try/finally is identical between the threaded and non-threaded cases, so the huge difference in performace you can see there is the result of cache lines ping-ponging between cores and will not go away with x64.

Comment: +1 because it shows perfectly what [I've already seen about multi-thread scaling problem](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/07/15/Delphi-doesn-t-like-multi-core-CPUs-%28or-the-contrary%29) with the lock asm prefix used in the RTL.

Comment: @Jeroen @A.Bouchez My experience is that contention on the heap allocation is more significant factor than contention on the interlocked string ref counting. But I'm talking about a real application which actually attempts to do something. And yes the function does nothing. Nobody wants to read the length of a string and immediately throw it away. I can optimise that to `nop`. It becomes realistic when you read the length and perform operations on the string.

Comment: No heap allocation takes place when passing a string. That's the whole point of the ref counting scheme. And contention with heap allocations is much less of an issue if you use a memory manager designed to work well in a highly threaded environment (like NexusMM).

Comment: @Thorsten Most real world programs modify strings. It's at that point that issues with contention are much more serious. FastMM doesn't do a great job of allocating under contention.

Comment: @David, in the context of this question, modifying strings is out of the question as "const" will prevent that. Also, while I'm fully aware that FastMM doesn't behave all that well under heavy thread contention, I simply consider it a non-issue given that I have been developing NexusMM (since before FastMM was ever released to the public) as a memory manager that behaves relatively well in a heavily multi-threaded environment and have been using that exclusively every since.

Comment: @Thorsten FastMM is an issue for the majority of users though. As for me, I use malloc from the NT msvcrt.dll. If you want to restrict your discussion solely to string variables passed as const parameters then that's fine but I do feel that real world apps do more than that. Anyway, I think everyone's point of view is clear now and any future readers will have plenty of food for thought.

Comment: If `const` can speed-up execution of code, why not it used by default, since there is no functional difference between using `const` or not?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan There is a functional difference: a const string is **not allowed** to be modified, whereas a non-const string **can** be modified in the routine but won't affect the callers version of the string.

Answer (score 26):

Don't forget that `const` isn't only there to provide those tiny performance improvements.

Using `const` explains to anybody *reading* or *maintaining* the code that the value shouldn't be updated, and allows the compiler to catch any accidental attempts to do so.

So making your code *more* readable and maintainable can also make it marginally faster. What good reasons are there for *not* using `const`?

Comment: One good reason for **not** using const is that you need to create temporary vars if you want to manipulate the string before passing it on or doing something with it. These additional vars make your procedure longer, harder to read and longer to type. And besides everyone knows that parameters are passed by values by default and only declaring them as `var` makes them returnable. In fact the only reason `const` exists is because people figured out that `var` passing was faster and started misusing `var` passing to gain (often) tiny speedgains at high risks.

Comment: Thats right. Const is part of a good system for strong typing.

Answer (score 10):

Using const prevents an implicit try/finally block which on x86 is rather more expensive than reference counting. That's really a separate issue to the semantic meaning of const. It's a shame that performance and semantics are mixed up in this way.

Comment: So, how would you go about separating the performance and semantics implications?

Comment: @thorsten I don't have a solution. I just think it's a shame.

Comment: Then you might as well think it's a shame that the earth is a ball orbiting around the sun instead of a disc on the back of 4 elephants standing on a turtle floating through space. :)

Comment: A very valuable insight David.

Comment: The statement that "an implicit try/finally block (...) on x86 is rather more expensive than reference counting" is factually wrong. A try/finally block takes just 2 push and one mov instruction to install (try) and 2 push and one mov instruction to uninstall (finally). Reference counting involves a call to UStrAddRef and a call to UStrClr. Besides the overhead of call for each, AddRef contains a test, a mov, 2 conditional jumps and 2 incs, one of which has a lock prefix and Clr contains 3 mov, test, 3 conditional jump and 2 dec, one of which has a lock prefix (in the most common code path).

Answer (score 5):

The type **String** is a special case, because it is managed by Delphi (copy on demand), and therefore not ideal to answer your question.

If you test your function with other types that are bigger than a pointer, records or arrays for example, you should see a bigger time difference, because with `const` only a pointer is passed, without `const` the record would be copied before passing to the function.

Using the keyword const, you can leave the decision of optimization to the compiler.

Comment: I asked about string, because that was my whole point, strings always get passed by reference, so what's the fuss (now I know).

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters) says:

> *Using const allows the compiler to optimize code for structured- and string-type parameters.*

So, it is better, thus rational, to use **const** for string parameters, simply because the manual says so. ;)

---

Now, this may be well enough an answer for the questioner, but it is even more interesting to look at the general question whether to use const parameters or not.

Again, the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control#By_Value_vs._By_Reference) says at just one click away from the *Delphi Language Guide Index*:

> *Value and constant (**const**) parameters are passed by value or by reference, depending on the type and size of the parameter:*

Note the apparent equality of value and constant parameters in this sentence. This concludes that using **const** for parameters, being not string- or structured-typed, makes no difference in performance nor code-size. (A short test, derived from Thorsten Engler's test code, indeed shows an average indifference between with and without const for parameters of ordinal and real types.)

So it turns out that whether or not using **const** only makes a difference to the programmer, not the executable.

As follow-up, and as LukeH already asked: What good reasons are there for *not* using **const**?

1. To follow Delphi's own syntax:

   ```
   function FindDragTarget(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean): TControl;
   function UpperCase(const S: string): string;
   function UpCase(Ch: Char): Char;
   function EncodeDate(Year, Month, Day: Word): TDateTime;
   ```
2. To produce more compact are therefore possibly slightly more readable code. For instance: using constant parameters in property setters really is superfluous, which surprisingly often leads to single line declarations instead of double, if you like to honour a line length limit.
3. To comfortably provide variables to virtual methods and event handlers. Note that none of the VCL event handler types use **const** parameters (for other than string- or record-typed members). It is just nice service for the users of your code or your components.

Of course, there also may be fine reasons for using **const**:

1. As LukeH already answered, if there is really no need at all to change the value of the parameter.
2. For (personal) protection, like the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters) says:

   > *Using **const** also provides a safeguard against unintentionally passing a parameter by reference to another routine.*

<sub>Partial origin of this answer: [http://www.nldelphi.com](http://www.nldelphi.com/Forum/showthread.php?p=271371#post271371).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would avoid any optimizations (in any language) that don't solve real problems that you can measure. Profile your code, and fix the problems that you can actually see. Optimizing for theoretical issues is just a waste of your time.

If you suspect that something is wrong, and this somehow fixes it/speeds it up, then great, but implementing these kinds of micro optimizations by default are rarely worth the time.

Comment: Is it a waste of time writing five letters (`const`)?

Comment: Well, if it provides zero value, then yes it is quite obviously a waste of time. I'm certainly not saying that you should avoid using const altoghter - clearly you should when something needs to be constant. But using "const" for speed alone is like Homer Simpson shooting "speed holes" in his car.

Comment: As my benchmark shows, a speedup of the factor 6 for simple leaf functions isn't exactly "zero value", is it?

Comment: And never forger the 'const' helps auto-documentation.

Comment: @Thorsten - Agreed. If it provides measurable value in a particular situation (or class of situations), then I am for it.

Comment: I like const because it is one more way to limit scope.  And limiting scope is a Good Thing(tm).

Comment: Think about _why_ you shouldn't do premature optimization, it's because you shouldn't add more complexity to your code, for nothing more than a bit of speed gain. The `const` keyword does the opposite, it can (in the right circumstances) speed things up and makes your code even more readable. You shouldn't ignore optimizations as well.

Comment: I think we're at a philosophical cross roads. Makes me want to write a language that has a "speedup" keyword for all functions, and if you want things to be faster, you just declare your functions with the "speedup" modifier. :)

Comment: That would be very useful indeed :-) Maybe you should have a look at my answer (the last one), it explains when `const` can speedup a function and why it doesn't in the example.

Comment: @ThorstenEngler Yes, your benchmark shows a significant improvement in a method that searches for a specific character in a (very short) 6 character string. And even more of an improvement in a method that simply returns the length of a string. However, in a method that validates XML strings > 100 KB in length, how much of a performance improvement will you see?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important fact that people omitted. Interlock ... instruction is very costly in Multicore CPUs of x86 instruction. Read Intel manual. The cost is when refcounter var is taken placed and it is not in cpu cache, ALL other CPUs must be stopped for instruction to carried out.

Cheers

Comment: That's not right. Interlocked operations do not "stop all other cpu's". They are slower because they enforce cache coherency for the involved cache line on all cores which have this line in their cache right now. But the naive implementation of "make all cpu's in the system stop, then perform the operation, then release them" hasn't been seen in hardware on the x86 platform for at least a decade. For some more information, read e.g. http://blogs.sun.com/dave/entry/biased_locking_in_hotspot starting at 'A common myth is that each CAS operation "goes on the bus"'

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question at all.